# Configuration Element Collection Section

Tags: .net, vb.net, app-config

I would like to set up a custom app configuration element collection section like this

```
<logSectionGroup>
    <logSection name="Testttt">
        <properties name ="Pride">
           <pathName="TestingLog.txt"/>
           <deleteRetention="100"/>
           <deleteZeroRetention="5"/>
           <wildcard="*.txt"/>
        </properties>
        <properties name ="Adhoc">
           <pathName="blah.txt"/>
           <deleteRetention="70"/>
           <deleteZeroRetention="3"/>
           <wildcard="*.*"/>
        </properties>
    </logSection>
</logSectionGroup>
```

Is this possible?  Properties would be the configuration element, and log section would be the configuration element collection.  The problem is, I've only seen where you can have multiple instances of a single element instead of multiple elements.

```
<Section name="Section1">     
    <Section name="Section1">
        <SubSection name="SubSection1">
            <Item name="Item1" />
            <Item name="Item2" />
        </SubSection>
        <SubSection name="SubSection2">
            <Item name="Item1" />
            <Item name="Item2" />
        </SubSection>
</Section>
```

When you use GetElementKey() you have it return element "name" in the above example but how would you return 4 different elements like "pathName" "deleteRetention" etc.

Here is my Definition for PropElement

```
Public Class PropElement
Inherits ConfigurationElement

<ConfigurationProperty("pathName", IsRequired:=True)> _
Public Property PathName() As String
    Get
        Return CStr(Me("pathName"))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me("pathName") = value
    End Set
End Property

<ConfigurationProperty("deleteRetention", DefaultValue:="0", IsRequired:=False)> _
Public Property DeleteRetention() As Integer
    Get
        Return CStr(Me("deleteRetention"))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Me("deleteRetention") = value
    End Set
End Property
<ConfigurationProperty("deleteZeroRetention", DefaultValue:="0", IsRequired:=False)> _
Public Property DeleteZeroRetention() As Integer
    Get
        Return CStr(Me("deleteZeroRetention"))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Me("deleteZeroRetention") = value
    End Set
End Property
<ConfigurationProperty("wildcard", DefaultValue:="*.*", IsRequired:=False)> _
Public Property Wildcard() As String
    Get
        Return CStr(Me("wildcard"))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me("wildcard") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but you maybe still need an explanation.
You can't achieve exactly this, because of the nature of XML, you need a node name.

So `<pathName="TestingLog.txt"/>` is not valid XML - is the `pathName` a node or attribute name?

But these can be attributes, so you would have something like:

```
<properties name ="Pride" pathName="TestingLog.txt" deleteRetention="100"  deleteZeroRetention="5" wildcard="*.txt"/>
```

Then the code would look like this (I hope you can read C#, but if not, drop me a note and I'll convert to VB).

```
public class PropElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("pathName", IsRequired = true)]
    public string PathName
    {
        get { return (string)this["pathName"]; }
        set { this["pathName"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("deleteRetention", IsRequired = true)]
    public int DeleteRetention
    {
        get { return (int)this["deleteRetention"]; }
        set { this["deleteRetention"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("deleteZeroRetention", IsRequired = true)]
    public int DeleteZeroRetention
    {
        get { return (int)this["deleteZeroRetention"]; }
        set { this["deleteZeroRetention"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("wildcard", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Wildcard
    {
        get { return (string)this["wildcard"]; }
        set { this["wildcard"] = value; }
    }
}
```

All attributes required, but you can mark them otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

> When you use GetElementKey() you have it return element "name" in the above example but how would you return 4 different elements like "pathName" "deleteRetention" etc.

What you need to a type for each `<property>` element, derived from `ConfigurationElement` with four properties (defined to be elements themselves (i.e. a custom type derived from `ConfigurationElement` for each distinct type—otherwise they'll be attributes) and one a string (which you use as the collection key).

Then in the implementation of `<logSection>` the `Properties` collection can be marked as the default collection.

(Anything other than simple configuration structures does lead to a lot of types, but most of them are easy to create.)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?  I've added my code for the PropElements.  I'm not sure what you mean by collection key etc. 

Thanks